# How to get AWS SES to work well without a dedicated IP for SMTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I see in multiple places that Amazon believes that dedicated IP addresses for sending email are not necessary, 
[Here for example](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxZAFC38KWZ1FE/Amazon-SES-Now-Supports-Custom-MAIL-FROM-Domains#postCommentsTxZAFC38KWZ1FE). However, I can't find any more details. I would like to switch to SES but there are so many stories online where people believe their email is blocked by spam lists that I'm very hesistant.

Here is my question: Nick from AWS Support says what I have posted below. What is the "mitigation"?

> Please provide a more full story about why it is OK to send large
>   numbers of legitimate emails on AWS SES and not be concerned about
>   sharing IP addresses of the sending SMTP server.
>
> ---
>
> Thank you for the report. We mitigated the issue as of Apr. 04 03:19
>   UTC. Let us know if you have experienced any rejects dated since.
>
> Regards- Nick
>   Posted by Nick@AWS on April 6, 2016 5:37:09 PM PDT

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nick from AWS Support says what I have posted below. What is the
>   "mitigation"?

Mitigation of a black listed IP means they took corrective action by either a) having the IP rechecked by the service that black listed it in the first place, thereby removing it from the black list, and/or b) retiring that IP number from being used by the affected SMTP server.  In either case, those steps would resolve an IP black listing issue.

> How to get AWS SES to work well with out a dedicated IP for SMTP?

[AWS SES takes great care in monitoring bounces, complaints, etc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/deliverability-and-ses.html) and in preventing spammers from abusing its server for one specific reason: To **prevent their IP addresses from being blacklisted.**  They obviously have to do this if they are going to have a viable, reliable way of sending customer emails from SES.

I think SES does everything reasonably possible to prevent their service from getting blacklisted.  They have to manage this well, in order to maintain good deliverability rates in the future.

If SES works for you, then I would not be too concerned about lack of dedicated IPs.

As a sender, if you want to insure your email gets delivered, you still need to focus on overall deliverability. See [Improving Deliverability with Amazon SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/improve-deliverability.html)

NOTE: The greatest risk with SES is that they shut down your service if you cross one of their message bounce thresholds.  We had an automated test scenario running that was sending emails to a non-existent email address at Hotmail. They shutdown/restricted our access to SES for a few days till we sorted it out.  Be careful regarding testing and SES.

Comment: Thanks @RodrigoM I currently use SendGrid with a dedicated IP.  Before that I used sendgrid without a dedicated IP and every few months I'd have to deal with blacklisting.  Sendgrid always fixed it but now without bouncing emails in the process.  Any clue whether SES has dedicated IP's in their future, or are they thinking it's not necessary and likely will never do it.  I send about 150K emails a month to my user groups (under 10 spam reports) and would prefer SES because of their other services integration.

Comment: @PeterKellner https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/amazon-ses-now-offers-dedicated-ip-addresses/

Comment: From what I've seen, spam/complaints is an even greater risk than bounces as the threshold is much lower than bounce threshold - 50x lower in fact according to their "expected" level (5% versus 0.1%). It's easy to go above the level when starting to use it, then it becomes a lot easier once there are repeat recipients established.

Comment: Either way, need to be ready to detect both bounces and complaints via SNS and back off from sending.